# Dynamic Button in ejs to fill a form-field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ejs

i am currently using NodeJS with ejs Templates an a mySQL Database.
I created an ejs which can print a table dynamically which represents a table in the Database:

The Code looks like this:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++) {%>
        <tr>
                <td><b><%= info[i].id %></b></td>

                <td><%= sinfo[i].path %></td>                       
        </tr>
<% } %>
```

This work fine.

Somewhere in the same ejs you can find form with an input field.

**Looks like this:**

```
<input type="text" name="id" placeholder="id input"required>
```

Now i want to create a button in every row of the table.
When pressing the button the id-entry out of the colum where the button is in should be filled into my Form-Field. So every row would have one button!

I can't find a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++) {%>
        <tr>
                <td><b><%= info[i].id %></b></td>
                <td><%= info[i].path %></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myText').value='<%= info[i].id %>'" value="Click" /></td>             
        </tr>
<% } %>
```

Than set the id `myText` to your input text:

```html
<input type="text" name="id" id="myText" placeholder="id input">
```

A cleaner solution is to create a function somewhere in your javascript code:

```
function onClick(id){
  document.getElementById('myText').value=id;
}
```

And so your ejs code will be:

```
<% for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++) {%>
        <tr>
                <td><b><%= info[i].id %></b></td>
                <td><%= info[i].path %></td>
                <td><input type="button" onclick="onClick('<%= info[i].id %>')" value="Click" /></td>             
        </tr>
<% } %>
```